# access js from outside root folder

Tags: javascript, apache, root

using apache web server and javascript/php webpage,
is there ANY WAY to include javascript exist outside the root as a script in the index (html file) ?

Comment: sorry, can you re-state your question? What do you mean by "include javascript exist" ?

Comment: i meant include a javascript file that i put it outside the root folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client only have access to files made available by the server, you can make directories outside of the document root available with alias

```
Alias /js /path/to/js
<Directory "/path/to/js">
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

(I'm not to sure about the `Require all granted` part, but without it I get access denied)
Then you can access the /js folder form example.com/js

Comment: Thanks! but just wondering if that would lower security and let anyone access that folder ?

Answer (score 1):

You can only include files which are **publicly** available.

Comment: you mean just inside the root ?

Comment: @Oxi if I can go to `www.pathtoyourjs.com/yourjs.js` from my browser, then you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript, via the `<script type="text/javascript" src="myurl">` can be included from anywhere. The browser takes it all in, regardless of the source.

Off-topic P.S.: That's why jsonp works for cross-domain requests.

*EDIT:* Your question's a bit ambiguous, but reading @Neal's answer, I think he's likely addressing what you meant to ask.

Comment: still not understanding. what do you mean by (publicly available) ?